# jquery how to select form elements in sub-form div

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, selector, subform

say I have the following form:

​

```
​<form id="f">
    <input name="a"/>
    <input name="b"/>
    <div id="sub_part">
        <input name="c"/>
        <input name="d"/>
    </div>
</form>
<form id="e">
    <input name="a"/>
    <input name="b"/>
    <div id="sub_part2">
        <input name="c"/>
        <input name="d"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I usually can get all the name->value pairs using `.serialize()`.  For example. I know i can get the information from form `f` by using:

```
$('form#f').serialize();
```

What if just want the name->value pairs from the `sub_part` div in form `f`?  What would the jquery selector be in this case?  For this exercise I do not want to change the structure of the html.

Please check out this fiddle where I have the problem outlined: http://jsfiddle.net/gu9XB/4/

Notice way I am trying to select the sub form is not working.

Comment: jQuery docs are confusing when it says `.serialize()` "operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements". It doesn't, the only officially supported element (as a container) is `form`. Maybe they will fix the docs. See related [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11594).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
$('#but1').click(function() {
    var data = $('form#f').serialize();
    alert(data);
});

$('#but2').click(function() {
    var data = $('#f #sub_part *').serialize();
    alert(data);
});​
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gu9XB/20/)

Comment: Why use 'form' selector when ID is already given and is a lot faster?  Also using #f #sub_part?  You can just use the ID '#sub_part' which is the fastest way to select an element

Answer (score 4):

Just serialize the inputs inside the div.  You were also using .sub_part so it was not selecting the div.  If there's already an ID you can just select by id to make it faster

```
('#sub_part input').serialize();
```

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gu9XB/21/

Answer (score 1):

use the following code 
it will work in you case

```
 $('#f #sub_part input').serialize();
```

Comment: here is jsfiddle working even if you have same id in both forms http://jsfiddle.net/8XXDn/1/

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answers the serialize() method won't work against a div. A way around this is to create a jQuery object that it will work on and append your selected elements to this:

```
var data = $('<form>').append($('form#f .sub_part')).serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS selector

```
$('#e > div')
```

That will select the `sub_part` div. The match occurs because it is a direct child of the form  element. If there is a div nested within `sub_part` it will not be affected.

Also you have a repeating id with sub_part. You should change the id to a class or change the name of one of the ids.

http://jsfiddle.net/dceast/gu9XB/15/

Comment: This method is not working for me in the jsfiddle example.  If you think it works then please post a working example using the jsfiddle i provided.

Comment: You should be serializing on a form, input, text area, or select not a sub div, so you need to break it out. http://jsfiddle.net/dceast/gu9XB/15/